# Add back button in App bar of tab bar in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to add back button in app bar of tab bar view.

When you push a tab bar view controller on to the navigation stack, i am unable see a back button in app bar of tab menu. When i swipe left to right i am going to previous screen, but i am unable to see backbutton in app bar

below is how i pushing tab bar in to navigation stack

```
Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => TabBarScreen()),
              );


class TabBarScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
            automaticallyImplyLeading: true,

          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because yours `TabBarScreen` has a `MaterialApp` inside, it has its own `Navigator` and its own navigation stack. So, for its perspective, it is at the "first screen".

If you remove the `MaterialApp` widget from the widget tree you will see the back button.

This is what I mean:

```dart
class TabBarScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
            ],
          ),
          title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.directions_car),
            Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
            Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are not using the `Navigator` linked here, there should be no back button and I can't understand why you would want one unless I am misunderstanding what you are asking.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html

The `tabBarView` is not changing the page, just the display. You are just controlling the widgets of the `body`. If you want there to be a back button you would need to hard code an `iconButton` in the `appBar` for specifically the second/third screen and have that button `setState` the `selectedIndex` which can then swap the widget in the body in the same manner as the `tabBarView`.

I am no expert but I hope this helps even a little or points you in the right direction!